# Листать вверх без перескока вниз

Tags: windows, cmd

Когда в `cmd.exe` выполняется какой-либо долгий процесс, выводящий debug info, иногда хочется почитать предупреждение или другую информацию, т.е. "остановить окошко" на определенном месте вывода. Однако при появлении новой записи окно смещается вниз. Можно ли как-то изменить это поведение, т.е. чтобы в любом месте (пока буфер позволяет) можно было остановить и спокойно читать, пока новые записи выводятся где-то снизу?

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью внешних модов. На гитхабе готовый проект [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console/wiki).
Фактически это расширение с множеством функций: цвета, стили,текстовый редактор, множественные вкладки и пр.